# How open replaced link in a new tab via javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you can see the below code - i am using it to replace a link on the page via javascript. All I want is that when replaced link is clicked i.e *https://boxoffice.com* in this case - it should open in a new tab...

```js
$(function() {
  var relativeUrl = "http://funmaza.com";
  var menuItem = $('a[href="' + relativeUrl + '"]');
  if (menuItem) {
    menuItem.attr("href", "https://boxoffice.com");
  }
})
```

Comment: Note that what you are using is JavaScript. Java is an entirely different beast.

Comment: use target:_blank

Answer (score 3):

To achieve what you require you can add a `target` attribute to the `a` element. Also note that the `if` is redundant as jQuery objects are very tolerant. They will not error if you call a method on an object which holds no DOM elements. Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href="http://funmaza.com"]').attr({
    href: 'https://boxoffice.com',
    target: '_blank'
  });  
});
```

Comment: my knowledge is very weak regarding this...can you please apply your answer into my code and send it to me? ...so that i just copy paste it... dont know how to apply your answer to my code... :)

Comment: I can a smell a spam attempt with above code snippet. Inject this code to any page, replace actual links with some spam links. Hmm. Now, I understand how the spam links work actually. :) Thanks for the snippet.

Comment: @EvelynJeanett It's pretty much the same, but I removed the document.ready handler. I updated the answer to give you the whole thing

Comment: thank you so much it worked... :) ...Also can you tell me how to replace any link that starts with http://stores.ebay and replace it with www.boxoffice.com and make it open in a new tab...

Answer (score 0):

You can try with it.

```
$(document).find("a[href="http://funmaza.com"]").attr({href:'https://boxoffice.com'});
```